# Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String but no hashmap in code?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap, runtime-error

I am trying to display data that has been added to my Firebase database to android. The data is uploaded to the database fine, but I get the following error when I try to display it through a phone or emulator:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert
>   value of type java.util.HashMap to String

at the following:

> com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:147)

This is the code at line 146 and 147:

```
protected T parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.getValue(mModelClass);
}
```

This error causes the application to crash and not run. I believe the error is to due with this piece of code in my MainActivity class as when I remove the .child element the app will run, but obviously not display the data.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
```

I'm not sure why this error is being thrown as the only data types I have in the database are Strings, and the child "Blog" is spelled correctly in my database.

**Another important piece of info:**
The app will run when I delete the "Blog" child in firebase. However, once I submit data to firebase the error occurs and my app crashes.

Any help would be appreciated,

This class displays the data:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mPostList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

        mPostList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_list);
        mPostList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mPostList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.post_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
                ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
            }
        };

        mPostList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            TextView post_desc = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image) {
            ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId()== R.id.action_add){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This class posts data to firebase:

```
package infectionapp.com.infectionui;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton mSelectImage;
    private Uri  mImageUri = null;
    private EditText mPostTitle;
    private EditText mPostDesc;
    private Button mSubmitBtn;

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

   // private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        //Directs to root firebase storage
        mSelectImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

        mPostTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        mPostDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descField);
        mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);

    //    mProgress = new ProgressBar(this);

        mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startPosting();

            }
        });

        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startPosting() {

       final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
       final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null){
                StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Post_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

                filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                        //Creates unique ID for post
                        DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                        newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                        newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                        newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).toString();

                        startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

        }
    }
}
```

[Database structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkq7Z.png)

[Child nodes within children:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpr95.png)

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1BMQ.png)

[Error of updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOAl3.png)

Comment: Share us your database structure.

Comment: I've added it at the end. Note when the child element "Blog" is deleted, the app will post to database. It crashes after trying to post to it once it's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that data in the simplest way, i recomand you using this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference blogRef = rootRef.child("Blog");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String desc = ds.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            String image = ds.child("image").child("path").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", desc + " / " + title + " / " + image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
blogRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
tst / test / /v0/b/infectionui...
```

As you see, i have used String class. This is what you need to use also in your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

If you want to get antoher value from image, just change `.child("path")` with another child, let's say `.child("schemeSpecificPart")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex, I've implemented your code, however the same issue still resides. I've added an image of the children within the image node. These are auto incremented.

Comment: There's a very big difference between those two screenshots. The fist was incomplete. Tell me now, the exact values you to get and i will write you the code again.

Comment: My bad. On my UI I've a cardview that should display the Image, with the title and description that is stored in the "Blog" node. 
See the following code, I do not create the other elements in the "image" node

 DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                        newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                        newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                        newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).toString();

Comment: I do not understand you entirely. Please add o screenshot where do underline the data you want to get.

Comment: I have an application where the user can upload an image, title, and desc in a post. The image is taken from the user's gallery, and the title + desc is simple text input. When the user posts (see the startPosting). This method then uploads the image jpeg to firebase storage, and uploads the title,image and desc to firebase data base under the root infectionui/Blog. 
I then want this "Post" to display the title, desc, that the user has uploaded. This code works when there is no "Blog" child in my root. However, as soon as it is added, the app crashes and therefore does not display.Thank you

Comment: So in summary I want to retrieve the image, title and desc under 'Blog' and display it. Thanks for investing your time in this.

Comment: Does it work now? Can i help you with other informations?

Comment: HI Alex, sorry for the long time for a response. This code has the same affect as my original code. It allows me to upload and display provided there isn't a node "Blog" in the database. Once there is however, the app still crashes. I've done some more debugging and it's something to do with the image upload, as when I comment the code for the images out it works perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean "there isn't a node "Blog" in the database"? As i see in your screenshot, there is one, the first one si named `Blog`. The code that i have provided you works only if you have this node in your database. If you have another structure, won't work. Which is your latest database structure? Add another screnshot.

Comment: The database structure is the same as above. Your code causes the same error once data is posted to the database.

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Comment: This is happening because the listener is attached in wrong place. Add a screnshot with your actual code. The code a have provided you.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot at the end as well as the error that occurs. Thanks again

Comment: As i see in your screenshot, the error is not caused by the code i wrote you, it is caused by a `ChildEventListener` which is `null`. Try to comment the line where the `ChildEventListener` appears and try again. Does it work?

Comment: I had mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog"); commented. Your code allows my app to run, provided there is no data in my database. Once there is data in there, the same error I originally had "Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String" occurs.

Comment: The coded that i provided you, does not contain any `ChildEventListener`. In other part of your code should be. infectionui is your database root?

Comment: Yes, the ChildEventListener error is no longer. The error "Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String" still occurs. infenctionui is my database root

Comment: If you comment `String image = ds.child("image").child("path").getValue(String.class);` Does it work?

Comment: It does not. The app will run, but as soon as data is added to the database, it crashes with the error above.

Comment: When  you are adding data, please use instead of this line of code: `newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).toString();` the following line of code: `newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());` and try again.

Comment: That works! I really appreciate the time you've given.

Comment: Done. Thanks again!